# Meassage "AUC-PR: the dataset only contains pos or neg samples"

Tags: xgboost

My goal is to fit column name 'My_Val' using columns 'B1','B2', I tried XGboost function as below. And "AUC-PR: the dataset only contains pos or neg samples" shows. I have no idea what went wrong? (※Dataset is organized as 'My_Val' is bigger when 'B2' is 'special' for all the categoies such as a,b,c,d,e,f in 'B1' column)

```
Dataset 'dataset.csv' file is as below.

B           B1    B2    My_Val
a_normal    a   normal  1.0
a_special   a   special 2.0
b_normal    b   normal  2.0
b_special   b   special 4.0
c_normal    c   normal  3.0
c_special   c   special 6.0
d_normal    d   normal  4.0
d_special   d   special 8.0
e_normal    e   normal  5.0
e_special   e   special 10.0
f_normal    f   normal  6.0
f_special   f   special 20.0
```

And my code is

```
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('M001_IN.csv')
df['My_Val'] = df['My_Val'].astype(float)

df.drop(columns=['B'], inplace=True)

X = df.drop('My_Val',  axis =1).copy()
y = df['My_Val'].copy()

X_encoded = pd.get_dummies(X, columns=['B1', 'B2'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_encoded, y, random_state=42)

reg_xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor(verbosity=0,  learning_rate=0.8, reg_lambda=10, seed=42)
reg_xgb.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose= True, eval_metric='aucpr', early_stopping_rounds=10, eval_set=[(X_test,y_test)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Precision Recall curve is for classification. The code and the target are for regression. Need to choose a different metric or a different target.

edit:
You can make an "analysis" target if the problem is applicable. For example, the problem would rather under predict. So if the prediction is less than the actual, fake_target = 1 else fake_target = 0. Then you can put that target into the precision-recall curve. If this is relevant to the business problem being solved.